# Which methods should be used for threads and copying files?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I have a method that will copy a file from one directory to another. The files will be huge and I want to use threads to ensure the console doesn't lock up.

What is the best method of using threads when copying files? I have read up and it seems there are three methods of using threads: Threadpool, Threads, Asynchronous methods.

Are there clear benefits of using one over the other?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are there any cases when it's preferable to use a plain old Thread object instead of one of the newer constructs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9894821/are-there-any-cases-when-its-preferable-to-use-a-plain-old-thread-object-instea)

Comment: If you only want to prevent the UI from freezing, do it in any other thread than the UI thread. Best way to do that: Backgroundworker.

Comment: I updated my example to show another alternative, using Parallel processing on a collection of file names.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to run it on a background thread, the recommended approach now (unless you need a specific reason not to) is to use [Tasks from the TPL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609(v=vs.110).aspx)

You can perform your file copy using the following code, which will run on a background thread.

```
Task.Run(() => System.IO.File.Copy(someFile, newFile));
```

If you need to perform additional code when the task is completed, you can do so with a continuation.

```
Task.Run(() => System.IO.File.Copy(someFile, newFile)).ContinueWith(() => 
    {
        // Some more stuff to do once copy is completed.
    });
```

#### Edit

An alternative, if you are performing a copy on a large number of files, is to run them in parallel. The TPL library handles the threadpool properly and ensures everything runs as it should.

```
Task.Run(() = >
{
    collectionOfFiles.AsParallel.ForAll(file => System.IO.File.Copy(file, newFile));
}
```

Or something more fancy if needed.

```
Task.Run(() =>
{
    collectionOfFiles.AsParallel().ForAll(file => 
    {
        string newFile = string.Format(@"C:\{0}", file);
        System.IO.File.Copy(file, newFile);
        // Do more
     });
});
```

That will copy all of the files, in parallel, on a worker thread.

Comment: Considering that the task will likely take a long time, shouldn't you instead create a task with the [TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskcreationoptions(v=vs.110).aspx) option, and then execute it?

Comment: You can do that as well, and probably should if he is copying a large quantity of files. If the number of files being copied is small (quantity, not size), then I don't know if you'd want to tell task scheduler that it can create more threads than available by the hardware by default. I would only do it if performance warrents it.

Comment: Actually, this sounds more like a use case for the AsParallel method. I updated my snippet to show an example.

Comment: You probably don't want the copies to run in parallel unless you know for sure that they're operating on completely separate drives. The disk drive can only do one thing at a time.

Comment: The disk can write both files to disk as the OS swaps between threads each cycle. You can see this when you copy/paste more than once in Windows. It just opens more "copying" dialogs.

Comment: The *operating system* can write multiple files concurrently. The disk drive, however, can only do one write at a time. If the OS is trying to write to multiple files concurrently, the disk head has to do more seeks, which means more time. When the limiting factor is the hardware (as it is when copying files locally), it's typically faster to copy one file at a time rather than try to copy multiple files concurrently.